# Displaying values in a column A if column B is the oldest date.

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having difficulties in my below table. Table A, is just a part of my present table upon           executing my script, there are other columns and rows but i just take out a part of it which i think can be useful to be able to understand my problem . Scenario: Customer buy an 10pcs of itemA with serial IA003 but when i execute my query it display TABLE A results. All I want is when a customer orders for 10pcs of a particular item then it should display inline with the serials of that item not all of the serials having that itemname. Or maybe, if a customer order for ItemA then it will look for the nearest expiration date whatever serials it has. 
    Many thanks

```
### Table A ### 

ITEMNAME ||    SERIALS  || EXPIRATION DATE  ||   SO_QTY      
ITEM A        IA0001         2014-01-20           10         
ITEM A        IA0002         2014-01-01           10        
ITEM A        IA0003         2013-05-13           10         
ITEM B        IB001          2012-11-08           15       
ITEM B        IB002          2015-12-28           15        
ITEM B        IB003          2014-06-01           15       


### how will i get this output? ###
```

### Table A ###

```
ITEMNAME      SERIALS      EXPIRATION DATE       SO_QTY      
ITEM A         IA0001         2014-01-20                
ITEM A         IA0002         2014-01-01                      
ITEM A         IA0003         2013-05-13            10         
ITEM B         IB001          2012-11-08           15          
ITEM B         IB002          2015-12-28                     
ITEM B         IB003          2014-06-01
```

Comment: It's difficult to see what you are having trouble with without seeing the code. Can you post what you have so far and explain where the trouble lies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the table with a subquery, *which gets the oldest `EXPIRATIONDATE` for every `Itemname`*, using `LEFT JOIN` so you can test if the record is the oldest for every `ItemName`.

```
SELECT  a.ItemName,
        a.Serials,
        a.EXPIRATIONDATE,
        IF(b.Itemname IS NULL, NULL, a.SO_QTY) SO_QTY
FROM    TableA a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  Itemname, MIN(EXPIRATIONDATE) min_date
            FROM    TableA
            GROUP   BY ItemName
        ) b ON  a.Itemname = b.Itemname AND
                a.EXPIRATIONDATE = b.min_date
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fad20/2)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (`with COALESCE`)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fad20/4)

Comment: Thanks sir for prompt reply. Will this query works in sql2008?

Comment: Hi Sir J W, how can i make this IF(b.Itemname IS NULL, NULL, a.SO_QTY) SO_QTY... work?